# how to raise custom exception inside function checking for empty pd dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, exception

function check_dataframe raises custom class exception if pd dataframe is empty. is there way to put the 'try raise' inside the function itself?

```
import pandas as pd

class EmptyDataFrameError(Exception):
    pass

def check_dataframe(dataframe):

    if dataframe.empty:
        raise EmptyDataFrameError("DataFrame is empty")
    else:
        print("DataFrame is not empty")

# Example usage:
try:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': []})
    check_dataframe(df)
except EmptyDataFrameError as e:
    print(e)
```

I expected to write the function check-dataframe as this:

```
def check_dataframe(dataframe):

    try:
        if len(dataframe) == 0:
            raise EmptyDataFrameError("DataFrame is empty")
    except:
        print("DataFrame is ok -process")
```

Comment: What's the point of putting `try` in the same function? You can just put whatever would be in the `except` block into the `if` block.

Comment: If you catch the exception in the function, the caller will continue running even though the dataframe is invalid.

Comment: Do you want to print the message and then raise the exception again?

Comment: just wrap it in an if / else block. use  [dataframe.empty](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7988029bcb07cc9712180d352b19573094c3cbf8/pandas/core/base.py#L677)

Comment: `check_dataframe` shouldn't print anything; it should only indicate whether the dataframe is valid or not by returning a Boolean value *or* by raising an exception. The caller can then decide what to do with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `check_dataframe` function to include the try-except block inside the function itself. Here's an updated version of your function:

```py
import pandas as pd

class EmptyDataFrameError(Exception):
    pass

def check_dataframe(dataframe):
    try:
        if dataframe.empty:
            raise EmptyDataFrameError("DataFrame is empty")
        else:
            print("DataFrame is not empty")
    except EmptyDataFrameError as e:
        print(e)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {ex}")

# Example usage:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': []})
check_dataframe(df)
```

This way, the `check_dataframe` function encapsulates the logic for checking if the DataFrame is empty and raising the custom exception if necessary. The example usage remains the same.